Typeorm with ManyToMany relation deletes data while updating
I have a ManyToMany relation with a pivot table, when I try to append new values including old values, Typeorm deletes old ones.
export class VHost {
//....
}

export class Migration {
  @Column({ name: 'migration_id', type: 'uuid' })
  migrationId: string;

@ManyToMany(() => VHost, { cascade: true, eager: true })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'instance_failed_vhost',
    joinColumn: { name: 'migration_id', referencedColumnName: 'migrationId' },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'dest_vhost_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'vHostId',
    },
  })
  failedDestVhosts: VHost[];
}

saving works fine like fr first time works fine, for updating: let's say failedDestVhosts=[VHost1, VHost2], while updating to failedDestVhosts=[VHost1, VHost2,VHost3,VHost4]
it inserts the 4 then delete VHost1, VHost2 from pivot table
I expect the 4 vHosts to remain after update

This is how many-to-many relationship work in TypeORM
If you want to preserve original entities you need to load it with the entity.
const migration = await migrationRepository.findOne({
  where: { migrationId: 'someId' },
  relations: {
    failedDestVhosts: true,
  },
});

migration.failedDestVhosts = [...migration.failedDestVhosts, newVHost];
// now you can save it

